# schema.org - q&a website markup

Tags: html, schema.org, rich-snippets

I'm using rich snippets on most of my websites now, specifically schema.org. I have one site that has a lot of question and answer type content, and decided to try tagging it up... but I haven't found any examples of snippets that seem applicable to this kind of structure. Since there is quite a lot of Q&A content on the web, I'm curious if I'm overlooking this tagging or if it actually is not included in the spec?

Comment: Here is better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27214259/272478

Comment: What about FAQ Page markup? I've been using that to good effect

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything in Schema.org specifically for Q&A sites but there is [a proposal](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/DiscussionSchema) to add schema to support them. I'm curious, what sort of structured data would you want to surface from your site and how do you envision that showing up in search? I'm working on an updated proposal and I'll post it to the W3C [public-vocabs](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/) list soon.