# Right way to set microdata for Q&A HTML

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

Say one has a simple question and answer HTML and would like to add microdata, how should one proceed?

```
<h2>My Question</h2>
<p>My Answer</p>
```

I am aware of the [schema.org](http://schema.org/Question) example, but I don't find it very clear. It looks like overkill. I need a simple solution. Can I proceed this way?

```
<h2 itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">My Question</h2>
<p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">My Answer</p>
```

I just want to tell what the question is and what the answer is. Is this enough for search engines? Or should I have something more sophisticated like:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
  <h2 itemprop="name">My Question</h2>
  <p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">My Answer</p>
</div>
```

Is using `itemprop="name"` the right way to tell what the question is? What is the difference between `itemprop="name"` and `itemprop="text"` in the schema.org example mentioned above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your first example, Microdata parsers will only learn that there is a `Question` and an `Answer` item, without any further content. Microdata doesn’t specify that the content of HTML elements with `itemscope` attributes has to be considered, it only cares about [property values](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values).

Testing your example with some [online Microdata parsers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13674/online-microdata-parser):

- W3C’s [Microdata to RDF Distiller](http://www.w3.org/2012/pyMicrodata/) extracts this RDF (in Turtle):

  ```
  <> md:item ( [ a schema:Question ] [ a schema:Answer ] );
      rdfa:usesVocabulary schema: .
  ```
- The [Structured Data Linter](http://linter.structured-data.org/) has almost the same output.
- Yandex’s [Structured data validator](https://webmaster.yandex.com/microtest.xml) has similar output.
- Google’s [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) doesn’t extract anything.

---

#### `name` vs. `text`

For this very question, the `name` would be "Right way to set microdata for Q&A HTML" and the `text` would be the question body ("Say one has a simple question …").

If the whole question consists only of such a single, short line, I’d use the `text` property instead of `name` (*). `name` could, principally, also be something like "Question 1", if you want/need it.

But you could also use both properties for a short question, i.e., `itemprop="name text"`, but this is maybe not very elegant (but it can make sense especially if you know that some data consumer makes use of the `name` property).

* The example for [`Answer`](http://schema.org/Answer) also uses `text` (and has no `name`).

---

You might also want to use Question’s [`suggestedAnswer` property](http://schema.org/suggestedAnswer) and/or Answer’s [`parentItem` property](http://schema.org/parentItem) to relate these two items.

So for a short question it could look like:

```html
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
  <h2 itemprop="name text">My Question</h2>
  <div itemprop="suggestedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
    <p itemprop="text">My Answer</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi @unor how to use ` parentItem` property, any examples?

Comment: @dr.dimitru: In Microdata, you’ll probably want to use the `itemref` attribute (as the question is typically not a child of the answer). -- If you have problems implementing it, I guess it would make sense to create a separate question for it (answer depends on your markup structure).